# Subsection Appears Twice

Tags: sectioning, pdf

I'm writing a report including images and pdf files, and I just realized there was a bug with the last subsections: they appear twice when I create the pdf [image: ![Short extract of the generated pdf]It only happens with the two last subsections, and I can't figure out why... Notice that I use the commands \pagestyle{plain} and \pagestyle{fancy} at lines 436 and 441 before and after adding my pdf files, in order to hide the header for those pages. Maybe there's a better way to proceed ? Moreover, section 7.11 doesn't appear in the table of content.
[image: Second image]

You can find the overleaf version here: 
https://www.overleaf.com/read/ggwypbtrnvxb

Any idea is welcome (the text is in french but it doesn't really matter) ;)

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an empty `\paragraph{}`?

Comment: Agree with @Sigur  You don't need to use those.  There are certain cases where you should explicitly use `\par`.  But for most documents, you simply put a blank space in between each paragraph.

Comment: note that it is really much better if you make a small example and copy it here rather than linking to an external site. Your question and any answers are archived here forever and will not make sense if you edit the document at the link in the question.

Comment: note that `\paragraph{This}` is a level 4 section heading and should only be used if you need sections that deep after section, subsection, subsubsection, **paragraph**,subparagraph

Comment: After looking through the document, I realized `\paragraph{}` is not used like `\par`, as I mentioned in my previous comment.  I had thought that because I saw a lot of empty `\paragraphs{}` at the beginning of each paragraph.  Either way, it's a bit strange to use empty ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `\footnote{}` inside the (sub)section is not supported by the table of contents here.  If you simply remove `\footnote{...}`, you'll notice that it works fine.

Of course, you want the footnote in the body (just not with TOC, or causing the problem that it does).  Therefore, you can use the optional argument of `\(sub)section{}` to give the footnote version in the body of the text and the non-footnote version for the TOC.  Change:

```
\subsection{Contrat d'équipe, fonctions, EPP\footnote{Les pages suivantes reprennent dans l'ordre: les deux versions du contrat d'équipe et des fonctions, les EPP individuelles et l'EPP de groupe}}
```

to

```
\subsection[Contrat d'équipe, fonctions, EPP]{Contrat d'équipe, fonctions, EPP\footnote{Les pages suivantes reprennent dans l'ordre: les deux versions du contrat d'équipe et des fonctions, les EPP individuelles et l'EPP de groupe}}
```

This works because the optional argument `[Contrat d'équipe, fonctions, EPP]` is passed to the TOC.  The required argument `{Contrat d'équipe, fonctions, EPP\footnote{Les pages suivantes reprennent dans l'ordre: les deux versions du contrat d'équipe et des fonctions, les EPP individuelles et l'EPP de groupe}}` is used by the text.

EDIT:
For those interested, I have created a MWE of the original problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Annexes}

\subsection{Poster pour le concours}

L’annexe 10 revient sur la réalisation d’un poster A3 présentant notre projet pour le concours qui a eu lieu pendant la semaine 12.

\subsection{Contrat d'équipe, fonctions, EPP\footnote{Les pages suivantes reprennent dans l'ordre: les deux versions du contrat d'équipe et des fonctions, les EPP individuelles et l'EPP de groupe}}

\paragraph{Contrat d'équipe} Au début du quadrimestre, nous avons eu l'occasion de nous réunir afin de convenir ensemble d'un contrat d'équipe. Pour une équipe efficace, nous avons par exemple décider d'être pro-actifs, d'éviter les distractions et d'aller droit au but.

\subsection{Planification (S9 à S13)}

Entre les semaines 9 et 13, nous avons été libérés de toutes contraintes horaires pour ne devoir se concentrer que sur un unique but: le concours lui-même. Pour ce faire, nous avons eu recours à un planning sous forme de tableau Excel que nous mettions à jour chaque semaine. Ainsi, pour toute tâche, il y était assigné une échéance et un ou plusieurs responsables à respecter méticuleusement.

\end{document}
```

[image: Original MWE - with TOC subsection problem]

After you modify the line as mentioned in my original answer, the outcome looks like this:
[image: New MWE - with modified subsection to fix footnote issue in TOC]

EDIT2:
You may look at this answer and think that it does not address your problem...  However, when I make this edit, it also removes the double subsection heading asked about in the OP.  When I make the MWE, however, I am having trouble repeating the doubled subsection...so there seems to be two things working together (one is the `\footnote{}` inside the `\subsection{}`...but I'm not sure what the other thing is).

Someone who is more familiar with the internals may be able to help.  But it does fix both the original problem *and* the issue of one subsection not properly appearing inside the TOC.

Comment: Thanks ! This totally solved my problem ! Have a nice day ;)